# How to save user input from a form into JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having some issues creating a feature. I have an html form which takes in users name and address.

I want to create a function that when the user submits the form that users information is saved into a JavaScript object.

Something like this:

```
Var person = {

       Name : abc,
       Address: xyz}
```

I was able to save the information into an object but when ever a new person submits the form the old info is overwritten. 
Is it possible to create a separate object for every user who submits he form.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: "when ever a new person submits the form the old info is overwritten". I don't know exactly what do you mean, but reading this, my first thought is that you're missing some basic knowledge about javascript.

Comment: I'll explain with an example: if "MARK" submits the form with the following info name = mark and address = London then the attributes in the person object hold this information. But when "JAKE" submits the form with info name = jake and address= America then attributes then hold the information entered by JAKE and not MARK.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn about arrays.

Comment: @quentin I took the data submitted by  the user and saved it into a variable and the pushed the variable into an array.Like so array.push(userName); but this does not solve my issue

Comment: @user2190986 — It solves the issue you described. You need to provide a more complete question.

Comment: keep in mind after pushing the data you need to then read it off of the array. if you read the `person` object you created you'll only ever get the last person you added to the array.

Comment: Wait a minute. Let's start over again. We're talking about users filling in the form on the same page or you're expecting this result from different pc/browsers ?

Comment: The issue is when I push data into my array the name attribute is being held at Index 0 and address at index 1. I want to save my user data into an object and then save that object into an array. So when I call index 0 I get both the name and address for that user form the same index. In summary im trying to save objects(containing data into an array)

Comment: @user2190986 — You aren't pushing data into the array in the way that the two answers you have been given show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = [];

// On some event
a.push({
  Name: newValue, 
  Address: newValue
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Would this solution mean that the name and address both will be held at the same index in the array. Meaning if someone submits the form for the first time the name and address both will be held at array[0] ? Again thank you

Comment: It really depends on how you are handling the submission. Is this all javascript, or a bit of backend as well? (like PHP, Ruby, etc)

Comment: its all JavaScript at the moment no backend. I only want JavaScript at the moment. The form is in html and the functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Cool, then each time you trigger the above event (considering that event doesn't leave the page) will populate the array with an extra person. After the first push, a[0] will contain person 1. After the second push, a[1] will contain person 2, and so forward.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just tried your solution and created an alert function to display the data at index 0. And it's coming up with the following message: [ object Object]  do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Its displaying correctly. You would need to do something like alert(a[0].Name) or alert(a[0].Address)

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman!bit worked thank you so much. I learned something new today!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the object you have to an array, then wherever you were populating the object, populate a new object and push it onto the array:

```
var people = []; // this is where var person was

function event_handler () { // assuming the object gets populated as part of an event
    people.push({
        Name: newName,
        Address: newAddress
    });
}
```

`push` pushes the new object onto the end of the array.